# Tried updating Pinescript code from V4 to V5 on Tradingview, but its slow on lower timeframes (Usually 1 bar behind), and doesnt match v4 indicators

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api

I've been playing around, trying to learn about writing and revising scripts for Pinescript V5.... and this time I took on Vumanchu's version of Market CipherB (for educational purposes only). When I finally got it added to the chart, I noticed its about 1 Bar behind on lower timeframes, and a few of the indicators don't match up (the Originals may have crossovers while my "attempt" is still following the trend and no where close to a crossover).  I've tried changing the offset from -2 (which is what it normally is) down to 0 too, but had no luck.  I know there's a few more warnings that popped up further down, but those were only in regards to the color update.  Any help would be MUCH APPRECIATED! THANK YOU!

Here's what I have....

```
// PARAMETERS {

// WaveTrend
wtShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show WaveTrend')
wtBuyShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Buy dots')
wtGoldShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Gold dots')
wtSellShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Sell dots')
wtDivShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Div. dots')
vwapShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Fast WT')
wtChannelLen = input.int(9, title = 'WT Channel Length')
wtAverageLen = input.int(12, title = 'WT Average Length')
wtMASource = input.source(hlc3, title = 'WT MA Source')
wtMALen = input.int(3, title = 'WT MA Length')

// WaveTrend Overbought & Oversold lines
obLevel = input.int(53, title = 'WT Overbought Level 1')
obLevel2 = input.int(60, title = 'WT Overbought Level 2')
obLevel3 = input.int(100, title = 'WT Overbought Level 3')
osLevel = input.int(-53, title = 'WT Oversold Level 1')
osLevel2 = input.int(-60, title = 'WT Oversold Level 2')
osLevel3 = input.int(-75, title = 'WT Oversold Level 3')

// Divergence WT
wtShowDiv = input.bool(true, title = 'Show WT Regular Divergences')
wtShowHiddenDiv = input.bool(false, title = 'Show WT Hidden Divergences')
showHiddenDiv_nl = input.bool(true, title = 'Not apply OB/OS Limits on Hidden Divergences')
wtDivOBLevel = input.int(45, title = 'WT Bearish Divergence min')
wtDivOSLevel = input.int(-65, title = 'WT Bullish Divergence min')

// Divergence extra range
wtDivOBLevel_addshow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show 2nd WT Regular Divergences')
wtDivOBLevel_add = input.int(15, title = 'WT 2nd Bearish Divergence')
wtDivOSLevel_add = input.int(-40, title = 'WT 2nd Bullish Divergence 15 min')

// RSI+MFI
rsiMFIShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show MFI')
rsiMFIperiod = input.int(60,title = 'MFI Period')
rsiMFIMultiplier = input.float(150, title = 'MFI Area multiplier')
rsiMFIPosY = input.float(2.5, title = 'MFI Area Y Pos')

// RSI
rsiShow = input.bool(false, title = 'Show RSI')
rsiSRC = input.source(close, title = 'RSI Source')
rsiLen = input.int(14, title = 'RSI Length')
rsiOversold = input.int(70, title = "RSI Oversold", minval = 50, maxval = 100)
rsiOverbought = input.int(30, title = 'RSI Overbought', minval = 0, maxval = 50)

// Divergence RSI
rsiShowDiv = input.bool(false, title = 'Show RSI Regular Divergences')
rsiShowHiddenDiv = input.bool(false, title = 'Show RSI Hidden Divergences')
rsiDivOBLevel = input.int(60, title = 'RSI Bearish Divergence min')
rsiDivOSLevel = input.int(30, title = 'RSI Bullish Divergence min')

// RSI Stochastic
stochShow = input.bool(true, title = 'Show Stochastic RSI')
stochUseLog = input.bool(true, title=' Use Log?')
stochAvg = input.bool(false, title='Use Average of both K & D')
stochSRC = input.source(close, title = 'Stochastic RSI Source')
stochLen = input.int(14, title = 'Stochastic RSI Length')
stochRsiLen = input.int(14, title = 'RSI Length ')
stochKSmooth = input.int(3, title = 'Stochastic RSI K Smooth')
stochDSmooth = input.int(3, title = 'Stochastic RSI D Smooth')

// Divergence stoch
stochShowDiv = input.bool(false, title = 'Show Stoch Regular Divergences')
stochShowHiddenDiv = input.bool(false, title = 'Show Stoch Hidden Divergences')

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcLine = input.bool(false, title="Show Schaff TC line")
tcSRC = input.source(close, title = 'Schaff TC Source')
tclength = input.int(10, title="Schaff TC")
tcfastLength = input.int(23, title="Schaff TC Fast Lenght")
tcslowLength = input.int(50, title="Schaff TC Slow Length")
tcfactor = input.float(0.5, title="Schaff TC Factor")

// Sommi Flag
sommiFlagShow = input.bool(false, title = 'Show Sommi flag')
sommiShowVwap = input.bool(false, title = 'Show Sommi F. Wave')
sommiVwapTF = input.string('720', title = 'Sommi F. Wave timeframe')
sommiVwapBearLevel = input.int(0, title = 'F. Wave Bear Level (less than)')
sommiVwapBullLevel = input.int(0, title = 'F. Wave Bull Level (more than)')
soomiFlagWTBearLevel = input.int(0, title = 'WT Bear Level (more than)') 
soomiFlagWTBullLevel = input.int(0, title = 'WT Bull Level (less than)') 
soomiRSIMFIBearLevel = input.int(0, title = 'Money flow Bear Level (less than)') 
soomiRSIMFIBullLevel = input.int(0, title = 'Money flow Bull Level (more than)') 

// Sommi Diamond
sommiDiamondShow = input.bool(false, title = 'Show Sommi diamond')
sommiHTCRes = input.string('60', title = 'HTF Candle Res. 1')
sommiHTCRes2 = input.string('240', title = 'HTF Candle Res. 2')
soomiDiamondWTBearLevel = input.int(0, title = 'WT Bear Level (More than)')
soomiDiamondWTBullLevel = input.int(0, title = 'WT Bull Level (Less than)')

// macd Colors
macdWTColorsShow = input.bool(false, title = 'Show MACD Colors')
macdWTColorsTF = input.string('240', title = 'MACD Colors MACD TF')

darkMode = input.bool(false, title = 'Dark mode')


// Colors
colorRed = #ff0000
colorPurple = #e600e6
colorGreen = #3fff00
colorOrange = #e2a400
colorYellow = #ffe500
colorWhite = #ffffff
colorPink = #ff00f0
colorBluelight = #31c0ff

colorWT1 = #90caf9
colorWT2 = #0d47a1

colorWT2_ = #131722

colormacdWT1a = #4caf58
colormacdWT1b = #af4c4c
colormacdWT1c = #7ee57e
colormacdWT1d = #ff3535

colormacdWT2a = #305630
colormacdWT2b = #310101
colormacdWT2c = #132213
colormacdWT2d = #770000

// } PARAMETERS


// FUNCTIONS {

// Divergences 
f_top_fractal(src) => src[4] < src[2] and src[3] < src[2] and src[2] > src[1] and src[2] > src[0]
f_bot_fractal(src) => src[4] > src[2] and src[3] > src[2] and src[2] < src[1] and src[2] < src[0]
f_fractalize(src) => f_top_fractal(src) ? 1 : f_bot_fractal(src) ? -1 : 0

f_findDivs(src, topLimit, botLimit, useLimits) =>
    fractalTop = f_fractalize(src) > 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] >= topLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    fractalBot = f_fractalize(src) < 0 and (useLimits ? src[2] <= botLimit : true) ? src[2] : na
    highPrev = ta.valuewhen(fractalTop, src[2], 0)[2]
    highPrice = ta.valuewhen(fractalTop, high[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrev = ta.valuewhen(fractalBot, src[2], 0)[2]
    lowPrice = ta.valuewhen(fractalBot, low[2], 0)[2]
    bearSignal = fractalTop and high[2] > highPrice and src[2] < highPrev
    bullSignal = fractalBot and low[2] < lowPrice and src[2] > lowPrev
    bearDivHidden = fractalTop and high[2] < highPrice and src[2] > highPrev
    bullDivHidden = fractalBot and low[2] > lowPrice and src[2] < lowPrev
    [fractalTop, fractalBot, lowPrev, bearSignal, bullSignal, bearDivHidden, bullDivHidden]
    
// RSI+MFI
f_rsimfi(_period, _multiplier, _tf) => request.security(syminfo.tickerid, _tf, ta.sma(((close - open) /                  (high - low)) * _multiplier, _period) - rsiMFIPosY)

// WaveTrend
f_wavetrend(src, chlen, avg, malen, tf) =>
    tfsrc = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, src)
    esa = ta.ema(tfsrc, chlen)
    de = ta.ema(math.abs(tfsrc - esa), chlen)
    ci = (tfsrc - esa) / (0.015 * de)
    wt1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.ema(ci, avg))
    wt2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.sma(wt1, malen))
    wtVwap = wt1 - wt2
    wtOversold = wt2 <= osLevel
    wtOverbought = wt2 >= obLevel
    wtCross = ta.cross(wt1, wt2)
    wtCrossUp = wt2 - wt1 <= 0
    wtCrossDown = wt2 - wt1 >= 0
    wtCrosslast = ta.cross(wt1[2], wt2[2])
    wtCrossUplast = wt2[2] - wt1[2] <= 0
    wtCrossDownlast = wt2[2] - wt1[2] >= 0
    [wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCrosslast, wtCrossUplast,     wtCrossDownlast, wtVwap]

// Schaff Trend Cycle
f_tc(src, length, fastLength, slowLength) =>
    ema1 = ta.ema(src, fastLength)
    ema2 = ta.ema(src, slowLength)
    macdVal = ema1 - ema2   
    alpha = ta.lowest(macdVal, length)
    beta = ta.highest(macdVal, length) - alpha
    gamma = (macdVal - alpha) / beta * 100
    gamma := beta > 0 ? gamma : nz(gamma[1])
    delta = gamma
    delta := na(delta[1]) ? delta : delta[1] + tcfactor * (gamma - delta[1])
    epsilon = ta.lowest(delta, length)
    zeta = ta.highest(delta, length) - epsilon
    eta = (delta - epsilon) / zeta * 100
    eta := zeta > 0 ? eta : nz(eta[1])
    stcReturn = eta
    stcReturn := na(stcReturn[1]) ? stcReturn : stcReturn[1] + tcfactor * (eta - stcReturn[1])
    stcReturn

// Stochastic RSI
f_stochrsi(_src, _stochlen, _rsilen, _smoothk, _smoothd, _log, _avg) =>
    src = _log ? math.log(_src) : _src
    rsi = ta.rsi(src, _rsilen)
    kk = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi, rsi, rsi, _stochlen), _smoothk)
    d1 = ta.sma(kk, _smoothd)
    avg_1 = math.avg(kk, d1)
    k = _avg ? avg_1 : kk
    [k, d1]

// MACD
f_macd(src, fastlen, slowlen, sigsmooth, tf) =>
    fast_ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.ema(src, fastlen))
    slow_ma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.ema(src, slowlen))
    macd = fast_ma - slow_ma,
    signal = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, ta.sma(macd, sigsmooth))
    hist = macd - signal
    [macd, signal, hist]

// MACD Colors on WT    
f_macdWTColors(tf) =>
    hrsimfi = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, tf)
    [macd, signal, hist] = f_macd(close, 28, 42, 9, macdWTColorsTF)
    macdup = macd >= signal
    macddown = macd <= signal
    macdWT1Color = macdup ? hrsimfi > 0 ? colormacdWT1c : colormacdWT1a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 0 ?     colormacdWT1d : colormacdWT1b : na
    macdWT2Color = macdup ? hrsimfi < 0 ? colormacdWT2c : colormacdWT2a : macddown ? hrsimfi < 0 ?     colormacdWT2d : colormacdWT2b : na 
    [macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color]

// Get higher timeframe candle
f_getTFCandle(_tf) => 
    _open  = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, open, barmerge.gaps_off,     barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _close = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, close, barmerge.gaps_off,     barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _high  = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, high, barmerge.gaps_off,     barmerge.lookahead_on)
    _low   = request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), _tf, low, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
    hl2_New   = (_high + _low) / 2.0
    newBar = ta.change(_open)
    candleBodyDir = _close > _open
    [candleBodyDir, newBar]

// Sommi flag
f_findSommiFlag(tf, wt1, wt2, rsimfi, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>    
    [hwt1, hwt2, hwtOversold, hwtOverbought, hwtCross, hwtCrossUp, hwtCrossDown, hwtCrosslast,         hwtCrossUplast, hwtCrossDownlast, hwtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen,     tf)      

    bearPattern = rsimfi < soomiRSIMFIBearLevel and
                   wt2 > soomiFlagWTBearLevel and 
                   wtCross and 
                   wtCrossDown and 
                   hwtVwap < sommiVwapBearLevel
                   
    bullPattern = rsimfi > soomiRSIMFIBullLevel and 
                   wt2 < soomiFlagWTBullLevel and 
                   wtCross and 
                   wtCrossUp and 
                   hwtVwap > sommiVwapBullLevel

    [bearPattern, bullPattern, hwtVwap]

f_findSommiDiamond(tf, tf2, wt1, wt2, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown) =>
    [candleBodyDir, newBar] = f_getTFCandle(tf)
    [candleBodyDir2, newBar2] = f_getTFCandle(tf2)
    bearPattern = wt2 >= soomiDiamondWTBearLevel and
                   wtCross and
                   wtCrossDown and
                   not candleBodyDir and
                   not candleBodyDir2                   
    bullPattern = wt2 <= soomiDiamondWTBullLevel and
                   wtCross and
                   wtCrossUp and
                   candleBodyDir and
                   candleBodyDir2 
    [bearPattern, bullPattern]

// } FUNCTIONS  

// CALCULATE INDICATORS {

// RSI
rsi = ta.rsi(rsiSRC, rsiLen)
rsiColor = rsi <= rsiOversold ? colorGreen : rsi >= rsiOverbought ? colorRed : colorPurple

// RSI + MFI Area
rsiMFI = f_rsimfi(rsiMFIperiod, rsiMFIMultiplier, timeframe.period)
rsiMFIColor = rsiMFI > 0 ? #3ee145 : #ff3d2e

// Calculates WaveTrend
[wt1, wt2, wtOversold, wtOverbought, wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown, wtCross_last, wtCrossUp_last,     wtCrossDown_last, wtVwap] = f_wavetrend(wtMASource, wtChannelLen, wtAverageLen, wtMALen, timeframe.period)

// Stochastic RSI
[stochK, stochD] = f_stochrsi(stochSRC, stochLen, stochRsiLen, stochKSmooth, stochDSmooth, stochUseLog,     stochAvg)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
tcVal = f_tc(tcSRC, tclength, tcfastLength, tcslowLength)

// Sommi flag
[sommiBearish, sommiBullish, hvwap] = f_findSommiFlag(sommiVwapTF, wt1, wt2, rsiMFI, wtCross,      wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

//Sommi diamond
[sommiBearishDiamond, sommiBullishDiamond] = f_findSommiDiamond(sommiHTCRes, sommiHTCRes2, wt1, wt2,     wtCross, wtCrossUp, wtCrossDown)

// macd colors
[macdWT1Color, macdWT2Color] = f_macdWTColors(macdWTColorsTF)

// WT Divergences
[wtFractalTop, wtFractalBot, wtLow_prev, wtBearDiv, wtBullDiv, wtBearDivHidden, wtBullDivHidden] =     f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel, wtDivOSLevel, true)

[wtFractalTop_add, wtFractalBot_add, wtLow_prev_add, wtBearDiv_add, wtBullDiv_add, wtBearDivHidden_add,     wtBullDivHidden_add] =  f_findDivs(wt2, wtDivOBLevel_add, wtDivOSLevel_add, true)
[wtFractalTop_nl, wtFractalBot_nl, wtLow_prev_nl, wtBearDiv_nl, wtBullDiv_nl, wtBearDivHidden_nl,     wtBullDivHidden_nl] =  f_findDivs(wt2, 0, 0, false)

wtBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBearDivHidden_nl : wtBearDivHidden
wtBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? wtBullDivHidden_nl : wtBullDivHidden

wtBearDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBearDivHidden_) ? colorRed : na
wtBullDivColor = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and wtBullDivHidden_) ? colorGreen : na

wtBearDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDiv_add)) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and     (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBearDivHidden_add)) ? #9a0202 : na
wtBullDivColor_add = (wtShowDiv and (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDiv_add)) or (wtShowHiddenDiv and     (wtDivOBLevel_addshow and wtBullDivHidden_add)) ? #1b5e20 : na

// RSI Divergences
[rsiFractalTop, rsiFractalBot, rsiLow_prev, rsiBearDiv, rsiBullDiv, rsiBearDivHidden, rsiBullDivHidden]     = f_findDivs(rsi, rsiDivOBLevel, rsiDivOSLevel, true)
[rsiFractalTop_nl, rsiFractalBot_nl, rsiLow_prev_nl, rsiBearDiv_nl, rsiBullDiv_nl, rsiBearDivHidden_nl,     rsiBullDivHidden_nl] = f_findDivs(rsi, 0, 0, false)

rsiBearDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBearDivHidden_nl : rsiBearDivHidden
rsiBullDivHidden_ = showHiddenDiv_nl ? rsiBullDivHidden_nl : rsiBullDivHidden

rsiBearDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBearDivHidden_) ? colorRed : na
rsiBullDivColor = (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv) or (rsiShowHiddenDiv and rsiBullDivHidden_) ? colorGreen     : na

// Stoch Divergences
[stochFractalTop, stochFractalBot, stochLow_prev, stochBearDiv, stochBullDiv, stochBearDivHidden,     stochBullDivHidden] = f_findDivs(stochK, 0, 0, false)

stochBearDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and stochBearDivHidden) ?     colorRed : na
stochBullDivColor = (stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or (stochShowHiddenDiv and stochBullDivHidden) ? colorGreen : na


// Small Circles WT Cross
signalColor = wt2 - wt1 > 0 ? color.red : color.lime

// Buy signal.
buySignal = wtCross and wtCrossUp and wtOversold

buySignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or 
               (wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv_add) or 
               (stochShowDiv and stochBullDiv) or 
               (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)

buySignalDiv_color = wtBullDiv ? colorGreen : 
                     wtBullDiv_add ? color.new(colorGreen, 60) : 
                     rsiShowDiv ? colorGreen : na

// Sell signal
sellSignal = wtCross and wtCrossDown and wtOverbought
         
sellSignalDiv = (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv) or 
               (wtShowDiv and wtBearDiv_add) or
               (stochShowDiv and stochBearDiv) or
               (rsiShowDiv and rsiBearDiv)
                
sellSignalDiv_color = wtBearDiv ? colorRed : 
                     wtBearDiv_add ? color.new(colorRed, 60) : 
                     rsiBearDiv ? colorRed : na

// Gold Buy 
lastRsi = ta.valuewhen(wtFractalBot, rsi[2], 0)[2]
wtGoldBuy = ((wtShowDiv and wtBullDiv) or (rsiShowDiv and rsiBullDiv)) and
           wtLow_prev <= osLevel3 and
           wt2 > osLevel3 and
           wtLow_prev - wt2 <= -5 and
           lastRsi < 30           
      
// } CALCULATE INDICATORS


// DRAW {
bgcolor(darkMode ? color.new(#000000, 80) : na)
zLine = plot(0, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50))

//  MFI BAR
rsiMfiBarTopLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -95 : na, title = 'MFI Bar TOP Line', color = color.red)
rsiMfiBarBottomLine = plot(rsiMFIShow ? -99 : na, title = 'MFI Bar BOTTOM Line', color = color.green)
fill(rsiMfiBarTopLine, rsiMfiBarBottomLine, title = 'MFI Bar Colors', color = rsiMFIColor, transp = 75)

// WT Areas
plot(wtShow ? wt1 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = 'WT Wave 1', color = macdWTColorsShow ?     macdWT1Color : colorWT1, transp = 0)
plot(wtShow ? wt2 : na, style = plot.style_area, title = 'WT Wave 2', color = macdWTColorsShow ?     macdWT2Color : darkMode ? colorWT2_ : colorWT2 , transp = 20)

// VWAP
plot(vwapShow ? wtVwap : na, title = 'VWAP', color = colorYellow, style = plot.style_area, linewidth =     2, transp = 45)

// MFI AREA
rsiMFIplot = plot(rsiMFIShow ? rsiMFI: na, title = 'RSI+MFI Area', color = rsiMFIColor, transp = 20)
fill(rsiMFIplot, zLine, rsiMFIColor, transp = 40)

// WT Div

plot(series = wtFractalTop ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT Bearish Divergence', color = wtBearDivColor,     linewidth = 2, offset = -0)
plot(series = wtFractalBot ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT Bullish Divergence', color = wtBullDivColor,     linewidth = 2, offset = -0)

// WT 2nd Div
plot(series = wtFractalTop_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT 2nd Bearish Divergence', color =     wtBearDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -0)
plot(series = wtFractalBot_add ? wt2[2] : na, title = 'WT 2nd Bullish Divergence', color =     wtBullDivColor_add, linewidth = 2, offset = -0)

// RSI
plot(rsiShow ? rsi : na, title = 'RSI', color = rsiColor, linewidth = 2, transp = 25)

// RSI Div
plot(series = rsiFractalTop ? rsi[2] : na, title='RSI Bearish Divergence', color = rsiBearDivColor,     linewidth = 1, offset = -0)
plot(series = rsiFractalBot ? rsi[2] : na, title='RSI Bullish Divergence', color = rsiBullDivColor,     linewidth = 1, offset = -0)

// Stochastic RSI
stochKplot = plot(stochShow ? stochK : na, title = 'Stoch K', color = color.new(#21baf3, 0), linewidth     = 2)
stochDplot = plot(stochShow ? stochD : na, title = 'Stoch D', color = color.new(#673ab7, 60), linewidth = 1)
stochFillColor = stochK >= stochD ? color.new(#21baf3, 75) : color.new(#673ab7, 60)
fill(stochKplot, stochDplot, title='KD Fill', color=stochFillColor)

// Stoch Div
plot(series = stochFractalTop ? stochK[2] : na, title='Stoch Bearish Divergence', color =     stochBearDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -0)
plot(series = stochFractalBot ? stochK[2] : na, title='Stoch Bullish Divergence', color = stochBullDivColor, linewidth = 1, offset = -0)

// Schaff Trend Cycle
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(#673ab7, 25), linewidth = 2, title = "Schaff Trend Cycle 1")
plot(tcLine ? tcVal : na, color = color.new(colorWhite, 50), linewidth = 1, title = "Schaff Trend Cycle 2")


// Draw Overbought & Oversold lines
//plot(obLevel, title = 'Over Bought Level 1', color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style =     plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel2, title = 'Over Bought Level 2', color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style =     plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)
plot(obLevel3, title = 'Over Bought Level 3', color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style =     plot.style_circles, transp = 95)

//plot(osLevel, title = 'Over Sold Level 1', color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style =     plot.style_circles, transp = 85)
plot(osLevel2, title = 'Over Sold Level 2', color = colorWhite, linewidth = 1, style =     plot.style_stepline, transp = 85)

// Sommi flag
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBearish ? 108 : na, title = 'Sommi bearish flag', char='⚑', color =     colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiFlagShow and sommiBullish ? -108 : na, title = 'Sommi bullish flag', char='⚑', color =     colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plot(sommiShowVwap ? ta.ema(hvwap, 3) : na, title = 'Sommi higher VWAP', color = colorYellow, linewidth     = 2, style = plot.style_line, transp = 15)

// Sommi diamond
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBearishDiamond ? 108 : na, title = 'Sommi bearish diamond',     char='◆', color = colorPink, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)
plotchar(sommiDiamondShow and sommiBullishDiamond ? -108 : na, title = 'Sommi bullish diamond',     char='◆', color = colorBluelight, location = location.absolute, size = size.tiny, transp = 0)

// Circles
plot(wtCross ? wt2 : na, title = 'Buy and sell circle', color = signalColor, style =     plot.style_circles, linewidth = 3, transp = 15)

plotchar(wtBuyShow and buySignal ? -107 : na, title = 'Buy circle', char='·', color = colorGreen,     location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)
plotchar(wtSellShow and sellSignal ? 105 : na , title = 'Sell circle', char='·', color = colorRed,     location = location.absolute, size = size.small, transp = 50)

plotchar(wtDivShow and buySignalDiv ? -106 : na, title = 'Divergence buy circle', char='•', color =     buySignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -0, transp = 15)
plotchar(wtDivShow and sellSignalDiv ? 106 : na, title = 'Divergence sell circle', char='•', color =     sellSignalDiv_color, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -0, transp = 15)

plotchar(wtGoldBuy and wtGoldShow ? -106 : na, title = 'Gold  buy gold circle', char='•', color =     colorOrange, location = location.absolute, size = size.small, offset = -1, transp = 15)

// } DRAW


// ALERTS {

// BUY
alertcondition(buySignal, 'Buy (Big green circle)', 'Green circle WaveTrend Oversold')
alertcondition(buySignalDiv, 'Buy (Big green circle + Div)', 'Buy & WT Bullish Divergence & WT     Overbought')
alertcondition(wtGoldBuy, 'GOLD Buy (Big GOLDEN circle)', 'Green & GOLD circle WaveTrend Overbought')
alertcondition(sommiBullish or sommiBullishDiamond, 'Sommi bullish flag/diamond', 'Blue flag/diamond')
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossUp, 'Buy (Small green dot)', 'Buy small circle')

// SELL
alertcondition(sommiBearish or sommiBearishDiamond, 'Sommi bearish flag/diamond', 'Purple     flag/diamond')
alertcondition(sellSignal, 'Sell (Big red circle)', 'Red Circle WaveTrend Overbought')
alertcondition(sellSignalDiv, 'Sell (Big red circle + Div)', 'Buy & WT Bearish Divergence & WT     Overbought')
alertcondition(wtCross and wtCrossDown, 'Sell (Small red dot)', 'Sell small circle')

// } ALERTS
```

what i've tried:
Tried updating all v4 functions to reflect v5 functions, but haven't changed colors farther down yet.
Tried changing offsets

Expected: the V5 revision to closely match the V4 original

Answer (score 0):

The code uses multiple *request.security* (11!)

Use the techniques to avoid [repainting](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#repainting-request-security-calls), and the signals will be displaced